# strpos not working on html tags

Tags: php, string

I have this code and for some reason strpos is not returning the positition of the title and /title.

```
$haystack = "<title> PHP Coding </title>";
$needle = "<title>";
//1. print the position of the $needle in $haystack
echo strpos( $haystack,  $needle);


$newneedle = "</title>";
//2. print the position of $newneedle in $haytack
echo strpos( $haystack,  $needle);
```

Comment: You can overwrite `$needle` with a new value. `$needle = "</title>";`

Comment: I know thanks was part of an assignment and missed the rename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine if you use the correct variable name in the second call:

```
$haystack = "<title> PHP Coding </title>";
$needle = "<title>";
//1. print the position of the $needle in $haystack
echo strpos( $haystack,  $needle);


$newneedle = "</title>";
//2. print the position of $newneedle in $haytack
echo strpos( $haystack,  $newneedle);
```

Comment: Thank you lol not sure sure why  i missed that

Comment: Be sure to tip your waiter. (i.e. click that little check mark there)